# Image Background in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Trying to load an image background onto my web project but its is not working. I tried using `style` in the body tag but still no success. I thought its maybe because of the path but even moving the img to the same folder so it can be loaded locally does not work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url(Images/red.png);
}
ul{
  width: 100%;
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>

<head>
  <title>Coding for fun</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>HEYY</h1>
  <h1>HEYY</h1>
  <h1>TESTING FOR IMAGE!</h1>
  <h1>PYTHON and DJANGO</h1>
  <ul class="navBar">
    {% for my_sub in my_test %}
    <li><a href="contact/"> {{ my_sub}} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Two attempted path for images:

first `User/..../mainfolder/images/red.png` This is in a subfolder.

Second `Users/.../mainfolder/red.png` This is in the html folder.

Comment: If you look in dev tools in your browser, does it give an error? What you have should work, provided your images are in a folder `Images` in the same directory as your HTML file.

Comment: You state that the img is located within the same folder, yet you are referring to a folder named Images from current directory. 

Take a look at relative paths

Comment: @disinfor The images are in that folder yes. Its is giving me an image not found error but not sure why.

Comment: @Albinwärme I was testing with that folder. As said in my post, i did try to load it without putting it in a different folder

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your folder/file structure?

Comment: Is your HTML in the `mainfolder` directory?

Comment: @disinfor Yes it is

Comment: As you can see here, the background image property works: https://jsfiddle.net/89Ldc3mk/. There is most likely an issue with the path to your image.

Comment: Ran the dev files on another laptop and it worked! not sure why it didn't work on my pc tho.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this `background-image: url(Images/red.png);`
to this `background-image: url('Images/red.png');`
Value inside of url() needs to be string

Comment: Even though I always use quotes, the code will work without it.

Comment: Try setting `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh` to body in css

Answer (score -1):

i would always give more arguments when handling a background-image. try manipulating the `body` as following (just an attempt).

```
body{
   background: #f9f9f9 url('images/red.jpg') center center no-repeat; //i recommend lowercase folder and file names
   background-size: cover;
}
```

also you may forgot to use quote marks on the file name?

Comment: he was asking about how to implement a background image.. thats what the code does.

Comment: Actually i tried with the quotes and without because some tutorials use both. it is giving me an error of not locating the image at all.

Comment: GabrielTheCoder, the problems in this case is in the file paths I would state. As OP said the quotes does not affect the result in css

Comment: @STOPIMACODER what if you try to move the `<style></style>` into the `head`? ive never used "inline styles" above the head-tag

Comment: still no success. I tried it before. @GabrielTheCoder

Comment: @STOPIMACODER The style tags need to be moved into the `<head>` tags otherwise you will have invalid HTML

Comment: I moved the dev folder and tried it on another Laptop and it worked. I'm not sure why it was failing on my pc.

Comment: maybe permission problems

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder Maybe but i tried with different files and none worked. Oh well a problem for another time lol